# Conditional and multiple goupby in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframe

```
        Location    Value
   0    x           1.5
   1    y           0.4
   2    y           1.6
   3    z           1.1
   4    z           0.8
   5    z           0.7
```

Each location has a different number of rows.
I would like to find the number of times a location has a value > 1, but with respect to the number of rows for that specific location.

```
    location  relative excesses
0    x        1
1    y        0.5   (1 row > 1 of 2 for location y)
2    z        0.33  (1 row > 1 of 3 for location z)
```

I tried many combinations of groupby, agg, transform, ... but I did not get any results. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

```
s=df.Value.gt(1).groupby(df.Location).mean().reset_index()
  Location  Value
0        x    1.00
1        y    0.50
2        z    0.33
```